# How can I use queue on custom class in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

In laravel 5.5 I was making an SMS service

```
SMS::to("xxxx")->send(new WelcomeSms());
```

or

```
WelcomeSms::message("xxx")->sendTo("xxx");
```

in here I want to use queue. When I call `sendTo` it must be work with queue. How can I do that?

Comment: Search for tutorials. For example: https://codebriefly.com/laravel-queues-tutorial/#Create_Job If you have any problems like "I'm doing this and it doesn't work", you can ask it here.

Comment: i looked at all but it talks about use queue on mailer but not in custom class as i say and I HAVE A PROBLEM "HOW CAN I USE IT IN <<CUSTOM CLASS>> LIKE SMSABLE ?" .

Comment: You can only dispatch a job in your custom class and send the SMS inside the queue.

Answer (score 3):

All about `Queues` in `Laravel` you can read in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#connections-vs-queues). You need to  generate `Queue Job` and dispatch `SmsMessage` from a controller:

**SmsMessage Class:**

```php
class SmsMessage {

    private $number;
    private $message;

    public function getNumber(): ?string {
        return $this->number;
    }    

    public function setNumber(string $number) {
        $this->number = $number
    }    

    public function getMessage(): ?string {
        return $this->message;
    }    

    public function setMessage(string $message) {
        $this->message = $message
    } 

}
```

**Controller:**

Then from a controller method dispatch some data and put it on the queue:

```php
class SmsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Send new sms
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function send(Request $request)
    {
        // Some code here

        $smsMessage = new SmsMessage();
        $smsMessage->setNumber('xxx');
        $smsMessage->setMessage('Lorem ipsum ...');

        SendSms::dispatch($smsMessage);
    }
}
```

**SmsQueueJob Class:**

```sh
php artisan make:job SmsQueueJob
```

It will generate a simple skeleton class:

```php
class SmsQueueJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $smsMessage;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param  SmsMessage $smsMessage
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(SmsMessage $smsMessage)
    {
        $this->smsMessage= $smsMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // Here send the SMS message
        SMS::to($sms->getNumber())->send(new WelcomeSms());
    }
}
```

> *You can generate new queue, new connection for this queue*

**To run queue worker run command below:**

```sh
php artisan queue:work
```

In production environment you should run this command as a `Cron Job` or use [Supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration)